# Visual Studio 2015 midl not found after Visual Studio 2017 Install

Tags: visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017, midl

I have WIndows 10 with visual Studio 2015 Update 3 working ok .
Before installing Visual Studio 2017 15.9.5 i see the following:
I run from CMD
"c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat"
And then 
midl 
[image: Midl Working]

After Visual Studio 2017 install i do the same 
[image: midl not working]

Please Advise
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Found and answer - specifically a workaround
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/22031/unusable-vc-build-tools-2015-installed-with-vs2017.html

**Solution by    Joseph Shen** · Jun 21, 2017 at 04:41 PM

I read the vcvarsall.bat source code, found that the VCVarsQueryRegistry.bat will try to enum the include dir for Windows SDK version. after install VS2017, Windows SDK 10 will be found. but this not the same as VS2015 install only status.

My fix is call with version specified like this:

%comspec% /k ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat"" x86 8.1

%comspec% /k ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat"" amd64 8.1

please note the 8.1 been specified!!